# PHP Populating Dropdown Select with data from database when it is inside Javascript tag

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

using the following code I can create unlimited number of rows with a dropdown select and a text input field in it. The problem is I want to populate the drop down select with data from my database but I don't know how to do it when I am creating the dropdown select inside javascript tag. I tried to use codeigniter's default drop_down select instead of the usual type of "drop down select" but when I click the add button to create a new row , it does nothing at all.

Would you please kindly help me to solve the problem? Just for your information I am using Codeigniter.

Thanks in Advance :)

Here's my javascript::

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {
    $("input[type=button][value=Add]").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
       var newDiv = $("<div>").appendTo("#div");
        $("<select>").attr("name", "fee_type[]").attr("class", "required").appendTo(newDiv).append(
         $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), 
        $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"));           
        $("<input>").attr("name", "fee_amount[]").attr('class', 'small required').appendTo(newDiv);                                                 

         $("<button>").text("Remove").appendTo(newDiv).click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          newDiv.remove();                                                  
        });                                             
         });                                               

        });                                             

</script>
```

I am using the following code to fetch the information I want populate within the dropdown select:

```
    function fee_types() {

            $this->db->select('fee_type,id');
            $records=$this->db->get('fee_types');

            $data=array();
                    $data[''] = 'Select'; 
                foreach ($records->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row->id] = $row->fee_type;
                }

            return ($data);
        }
```

Here's my Controller:

```
        $this->load->model('dropdown_fee_types');
    $data['records']= $this->dropdown_fee_types->fee_types();
    $data['main_content']='view_studentfee';                                               
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() {
$("input[type=button][value=Add]").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
   var newDiv = $("<div>").appendTo("#div");
    $("<select>").attr("name", "fee_type[]").attr("class", "required").appendTo(newDiv).append(
     <? 
       foreach($data['records'] as $key=>$value){
         print '$("<option>").val("'.$key.'").text("'.$value.'"),';
       }
    ?>        
    $("<input>").attr("name", "fee_amount[]").attr('class', 'small required').appendTo(newDiv);                                                 

     $("<button>").text("Remove").appendTo(newDiv).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      newDiv.remove();                                                  
    });                                             
     });                                               

    });
```

Never workt with codeigniter so not sure where the data is exactly put in...but the basics are also explained in the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: Hi, SomeOne_1.. thanks for your reply. I tried your code but still its not working. When I click on the add button to add a row it does nothing. But I figured out one thing that if I use foreach($data['records'] as $key=>$value){ inside the javascript tag it does not work. do you know any alternative.? Thanks

Comment: If you template the files then it would be fairly easy to parse, have a look at templating the html and javascript seperatly from your logic. Smarty is a fairly straight forward tpl engine, or you can make your own. :)